# Rails: send_data from a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a variable `recs` that stores the data I want to pass.
I want to have something like `send_data` as a button, so that I will not have to store an extra file somewhere. When a user clicks on the button, the send_data will send `recs` to the browser.

```
send_data(recs, :filename => "query.txt")
```

However, I was not able to find the representation of the send_data as a button.

Answer (score 2):

Define an action in your controller in which `send_data` executes. and add the respective route to your `routes.rb`. Then put a `link_to` this defined action in your view with required css class to show it as a button.

Comment: yep, but how will I send the 'recs' through the link_to ?

Comment: Try defining `recs`  variable in your action and pass it to `send_data`.

Comment: recs gets its full form in an action A and is displayed in a corresponding view. In this view I want to have a button that will send 'recs' to the browser. I cannot defined recs in an action B. The only way is to pass it through the link_to

Comment: Does your form corresponds to a model? do you store it in the database from  action A?